# Is there any way to set a specific date and time on linux machine through C Code

Tags: c, linux, date, root

**> I tried this code however it is not working without root privileges. Is there any way to use >settimeofday in C code

> Please go through the code and do let me know what can be done in this case
> gettimeofday is working fine but settimeofday is giving error. I am stuck on this from days and not able to figure out what can be done here**

```
'''
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #define ERROR -1
    #define OK 1
    typedef struct
    {
         int day;
         int mon;
         int year;
         int hr;
         int min;
         int sec;
    }tmfh_date;
    int main()
    {
         tmfh_date date;
         struct tm info;
         struct timezone tz;
         char buffer[1024];
         time_t ti;
         struct timeval T;
         int ret_Status = -1;
         //      time(&ti);
         //      info  = localtime(&ti);
         date.day = 12;
         date.mon = 12;
         date.year = 2020;
         date.hr = 0xFFFFFFFF;
         date.min = 0xFFFFFFFF;
         date.sec = 0xFFFFFFFF;
         FILE *cmd1 = NULL;
         if ((date.hr != 0xFFFFFFFF) && (date.min != 0xFFFFFFFF) && (date.sec != 0xFFFFFFFF))
         {       info->tm_hour = date.hr;
                 info->tm_min = date.min;
                 info->tm_sec = date.sec;*/
         }
         else  if ((date.year != 0xFFFFFFFF) && (date.mon != 0xFFFFFFFF) && (date.day != 0xFFFFFFFF))
         {        info.tm_year = date.year;
                  info.tm_mon = date.mon ;
                  info.tm_mday= date.day;
         }
         else
         {        info->tm_hour = date.hr;
                  info->tm_min = date.min;
                  info->tm_sec = date.sec;
                  info->tm_year = date.year;
                  info->tm_mon = date.mon;
                  info->tm_mday= date.day ;
          }
          ret_Status = gettimeofday (&T, &tz);
          printf("%d\n",ret_Status);
          T.tv_sec = mktime(&info);
          printf("%ld\n",T.tv_sec);
          if( T.tv_sec == -1 )
           {
                 return ERROR;
           }
           // T.tv_usec = 1000000*T.tv_sec ;
           ret_Status = settimeofday(&T, &tz);
           if (ret_Status != OK)
           {     //error position    
                 return ERROR;
           }
           return OK;
        }
'''
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question. You need to be `root` to execute `settimeofday`. You might do `perror` to be sure the error is `EPERM`

Comment: All of the functions that set the system time require special privileges.  `root` is the canonical way to get those privileges.  Your Unix _may_ have a "capability bit" that specifically allows a process to set the time without giving it any of root's other privileges, but not all of them do, and using those bits has uniformly been, in my experience, far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: You might consider making use of [privilege separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation) -- dividing your program into a tiny daemon that runs as root and all it does is accept requests, over an AF_UNIX socket, to set the time; and the rest of the program, which runs as an unprivileged user.  You can then use normal filesystem access controls to define which processes can ask for the time to be set.